# android:media controller

Tags: android, touch, visibility

I am playing the video in activity,I need to show/hide the topbar view along with media controller.so when media controller is in screen at that my top view should be visible and when the media controller hide ,my top view should be invisible.
  Can anyone tell me if there any listener is there in android.
  i have try with onTouch

```
private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {    
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                   if(v.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                       Log.d("TOUCH","ok");
                   }else{
                       Log.d("TOUCH","NO");
                   }
}
```

But the it is not working perfectly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this using the inherite media controller class inside the my activity using this code,

```
class MyMedia extends MediaController{

        public MyMedia(Context context) {
            super(context);
       }

      @Override
     public void show() {
          super.show();
          topbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

     @Override
    public void hide() {
         super.hide();
         topbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to hide the media controller if mediacontroller.hide didn't work

```
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(contex);
    MediaController controller=new MediaController(this);
    controller.hide();
    controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(controller);
```